# Laravel : how to use pivot table for taggable system

Tags: laravel, tags

I want create tag for posts

for example I created three new tags but submit a only a row in TaggablesTable

Tags Table:

```
  id  | name |
--------------
 1    | first|
 2    | two  |
 3    | three|
```

taggables Table:

```
tag_id|taggable_id|taggable_type
-------------------------------
 3    |      1    |post




public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $post = Post::create($data);
    if ($post && $post instanceof Post) {
       $tags = $request->input('tags');
        foreach ($tags as  $tag){
                 $newTag =Tag::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tag]);
                 $tags= $newTag->id;
        }
        $post->tags()->sync($tags);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting tags every time the loop runs. Map seems like an easier approach to your problem.

```
$data = $request->all();
$post = Post::create($data);

$tags = collect($request->input('tags'))->map(function (string $tag) {
    return Tag::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tag])->id;
})->all();

$post->tags()->sync($tags);
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Checking that post is a post in an if statement seems redundant.